# Yii: Вывод двух блоков меню одним запросом

Tags: yii

Есть двухуровневое меню, дизайнер разделил его на две части, над иллюстрацией основное меню (меню 1 уровня), под иллюстрацией подменю (меню 2 уровня). Т.е. получается как бы два вывода. Сделать все это дело одним виджетом не получатся т.к. подменю выводится в центральной колонке над выводом аннотаций постов, а основное меню находится в шапке.
Проблема в том, что я не хачу, да и не удобно два раза обращаться к базе. Теоретически я понимаю, что данные полученные из базы надо где ни будь запомнить при первом выводе меню (основного) и обратиться к ним повторно при следующем выводе (подменю), а вот практически не получается. Подсказывают, что для промежуточного хранения можно воспользоваться статической переменной класса, только вот какого? Данные для меню я получаю из модели. Как мне это реализовать ?

Comment: А что вам мешает получить все меню из БД и разделить на два массива, например top-menu и bot-menu, и не надо будет вам два раза обрашаться к БД

Comment: Я так понял, что следует это все дело получить в базовом контроллере а потом делить и выводить

Comment: Подкиньте пожалуйста код или вид меню что бы можно было что то сказать. У меня была похожая ситуация - мне кажется есть решение лояльней.

Comment: Я так понял что в базовом контроллере я получаю данные присваиваю их переменной, а потом из шаблона представления при вызове виджета меню обращаюсь к этой переменной контроллера. Пока объект контроллера активен переменная будет содержать данные. Попробую реализовать так.

Comment: http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3671

Comment: Постарение таблицы покажите

Comment: Код не тот - скиньте как вы получаете строение меню

Answer (score 1):

Без javascript тут не обойтись, если не получится сделать это спомощью css. Т.е. получаем полность сформированое меню, и выводим дочернее там, где оно нужно. (если очень нужно могу набросать пример с js)

Данные для меню из базы лучше кешировать (тут вариантов много, все зависит от хостинга).

Comment: Ну если можно, хотя бы примерно как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VasyOk/HzEms/ вот набросал, если конечно я правильно понял задачу :/

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант!